# navigator.contacts.find not working (cordova/phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-contacts, contacts

I am trying to access the contacts on a phone. I am using to code below to do so, but the navigator.contacts.find isn't working. It doesn't return an error or a success message. If I put any type of alert after that line of code it will not appear.

```
function read_contacts(){

var options = new ContactFindOptions( );

options.filter = "";  //leaving this empty will find return all contacts

options.multiple = true;  //return multiple results

var filter = ["displayName"];    //an array of fields to compare against the options.filter 

navigator.contacts.find(filter, successFunc, errFunc, options); //breaking the code

function successFunc( matches ){
    alert("reading contacts...");
  for( var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
    alert( matches[i].displayName );
  }

function errFunc(){
    alert("Error finding contacts");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Phonegap Docs**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts)

Try this -

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple = true;      // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName", "name"];   // return contact.displayName 
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts

function onSuccess(contacts) {
       for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts

function onError(contactError) {
     alert('onError!');
}
```

Try this code for finding all contacts with display name.

Comment: also include plugins related to contacts in config.xml. Refer above Phonegap doc for that.

Comment: interestingly, the cordova documentation is wrong. one can spend hours on this little things.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ol id="contact"></ol>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function read_contacts(){
   var options = new ContactFindOptions();
   options.filter="";
   options.filter="";
   options.multiple=true;
   var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
   navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// display the address information for all contacts
function onSuccess(contacts) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
   var li = '';
   $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
        if(value.name){
            $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
               if(key == 'formatted'){
                   name = value;
               }                      
            });
        }
        if(value.phoneNumbers){
            $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                phone = value.value;
            });
        }                    
        li += '<li style="text-decoration:none;">'+name+' '+phone+'</li>';
   }); 

   $("#contact").html(li);   
}

function onError(contactError) {
   alert('onError!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't ask for desiredFields :

```
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id, navigator.contacts.fieldType.formatted, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name, navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
```